# Javascript regex allow any character with comma separated

Tags: javascript, regex

In Javascript, I need regex to allow any character with comma separated in the textbox.

Example:
 Valid strings are:

```
ie, ch, mz
en, fa, ta
/path/xyz  , /test/apps/            
msg_abc_chec.ts, ss_msg_abc_chec.ts     
com.app.fr, vi.dsx;gui     
909.33.33.12312:343234, 33.23.33     
800x480,    200x480, 1200x1060  , 400x160      
Main app, sub app       
SomeAudOut#1   ,  SomeVidIn#3
```

Invalid strings are:

```
ie,, ch, mz   - 2 commas without string
en, fa, ta,   - comma at the end
SomeAudOut#2  - no comma separated value
```

Comment: Check [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/jD1lQ3/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
/^(?:[^,\n]+,)+[^,\n]+$/gm
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/vR2lQ8/2)

- `^` - start of line
- `(?:[^,\n]+,)+` - 1 or more sequences of

  - `[^,\n]+,` - 1 or more characters other than `,` (and newline, but it is only for multiline mode) and a `,`
- `[^,\n]+` - 1 or more characters other than `,` or `\n` (again, `\n` is necessary when testing in multiline mode).
- `$` - end of line

In case you also want to exclude `ie, ch, , , mz`-like lines, [use this regex](https://regex101.com/r/vR2lQ8/3):

```
^(?!.*,\s*,)(?:[^,\n]+,)+[^,\n]+$
```

Here, `(?!.*,\s*,)` prevents matching lines that have 2 consecutive commas separated with whitespace.

Comment: This input getting passed: `/test/apps/, ,/test/apps/`

Answer (score 0):

It should match this:

```
((.*)+,)*
```